# How to convert names(df) to a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many column names. I want to convert these column names to a new data dataframe.

`names(df)`

```
'SampleID' 'EMTSCORE' 'ESR1' 'PGR' 'ADCY1' 'TFF1' 'TUBA3D' 'SUSD3' 'CLIC6' 'FGD3' 'SCUBE2' 'PDZK1' 'SERPINA3' 'Mean' 'GrpMedian' 'Quartile'
```

I want to convert them as a new dataframe with `SampleID` as the header and other as row values?

```
SampleID
EMTSCORE
ESR1
PGR
...
...
Quartile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mock data frame to show how it works

```r
df1 <- data.frame(SampleID = letters[1:5],
                  EMTSCORE = LETTERS[1:5],
                  ESR1 = 1:5)
```

create a data frame from the names except the first one
(that is what the index `-1` is for).

```r
df2 <- data.frame(Dummy =  names(df1)[-1])
```

Use the name of the first column of the old data frame for the new one.

```r
names(df2)[1] <- names(df1)[1]

df2
#>   SampleID
#> 1 EMTSCORE
#> 2     ESR1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset:
We could use `names()` function:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Col1 = names(mtcars))
```

```
   Col1
1   mpg
2   cyl
3  disp
4    hp
5  drat
6    wt
7  qsec
8    vs
9    am
10 gear
11 carb
```